# Impossible recurrence relation help with masters theorem, plus evaluation of complexity

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

I had an exercise to solve a recurrence relation in my exam, I think it was a tricky question but I am not 100% sure.

The recurrence was $ T(n) = 2*T(n) + \sqrt{n} +42 $, it was specifically asked to be solved using the master theorem, and I wrote it cannot be solved using master theorem because it requires for b>1. 
Do you think is correct?

After that I had a small piece of code to evaluate, after a look at it I decided it was $ O(n^3) $

```
    for i in range(1,n):
      j = i+1
      while(j/n<=n):
        k=1
        while(k<=n):
            constantFunction(4) # a function that executes in constant time
            k=k+3
        j=j+1
```

In my opinion the function going from 1 to n, makes the while(j/n<=n) always be <=n as $ n-> infinity $, which makes the other while inside execute until k<=n, k will grow fast and soon that while loop makes me wonder, will it stop ? I mean let's assume n goes to infinity, then k will grow, but not as much as n, so it'll be $O(n^3)$. Am I right?

Thank you

Comment: A recurrence relation expresses $T(n)$ in terms of $T(m)$ for $m < n$. This is not the case for your recurrence.

Comment: So this was a tricky question from the teacher to see if we remember the definition of master theorem ? She clearly specified "Solve the recurrence equation using master theorem". She said equation, i referred to it as relation, but isn't a recurrence relation an equation ?

Comment: Your recurrence seems wrong. People make mistakes. The solution is $T(n) = -\sqrt{n}-42$, but it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: The recurrence I wrote here is exactly as the one I have in the paper of exam. So I assume my answer "It cannot be solved using Master Theorem" was correct. How about the complexity of the code? Do you agree it is $O(n^3)$? PS: The recurrence and the code do not have anything in common, the exercises are 2 separate ones.

Comment: No - your recurrence doesn’t make any sense. You need to accept that your professor is not infallible.

Comment: Sometimes she puts tricky questions on purpose, it's not the first exam she does it, that's why I wanted to know if I wrote the right thing by saying that it cannot be solved with master theorem.

Comment: It is not a recursion at all.

Comment: Yes, there is recursion for dividing and decreasing functions for example, and usually recurrence relation is T(n) = T(n-1) or T(n) = T(n/2), which can be solved with master theorem, but my teacher sometimes puts tricky questions like this "recurrence" relation, that is why I asked if it was solvable in any way, but you all confirmed my answer, that can't be solved with master theorem, because as you said it isn't even a recursion.